# TypeError: (0 , _dayjs.Dayjs) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dayjs

I want to replace momentjs with dayjs right now. First I added the dependencies:

```
"dayjs":"1.10.7"
```

then import the dayjs like this:

```
import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
```

get the month start using this code snip:

```
const fullDateTimeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:SSS';
const startOfCurrentMonth = Dayjs().startOf("month").format(fullDateTimeFormat);
```

but show me this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _dayjs.Dayjs) is not a function
selectMonthListState
src/components/SelectData/index.js:112
  109 | const days = getMonthDay(year, month);
  110 | const prevMonthDays = getMonthDay(year, month-1);
  111 | const startDateValue = `${moment(year + '-' + (month-count +1) + '-01').format(dateFormat)} 00:00:00:000`;
> 112 | const startOfCurrentMonth = Dayjs().startOf("month").format(fullDateTimeFormat);
      | ^  113 | const endDateValue = count ===1? `${moment(year + '-' + (month)  + '-' + prevMonthDays).format(dateFormat)} 23:59:59:999`: `${moment(year + '-' + (month+1)  + '-' + days).format(dateFormat)} 23:59:59:999`;
  114 | 
  115 | setSelectDate([moment(startDateValue, rPickerFormat), moment(endDateValue, rPickerFormat)]);
```

what should I do to fix this problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I using it like this:

```
import  dayjs  from 'dayjs';

const startOfCurrentMonth = dayjs().startOf("month").format(fullDateTimeFormat);
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
const relativeTime = require('dayjs/plugin/relativeTime');
dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

> "dayjs": "^1.10.4", import * as dayjs from 'dayjs'; import * as
> localizedFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/localizedFormat';
>
> dayjs.extend(localizedFormat);
>
> console.log(dayjs().tz('Asia/Tashkent').format());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).